# How to move <ul></ul> items right where the emphasized text starts but UNDER it?

Tags: html, css

**I've tried recreating google chrome's starting page of incognito mode. I'm just using this to practice, this wont be published anywhere.**

How do I move list items right under the  where it starts. I know that i could use stuff like
position: relative;
right; etc but if i do do that with every single item i wanna move to the specific place it wont be aligned perfectly because i can't always guess the number of pixels accurately. I thought about making a hidden border but i'm not sure if it would help. By the way, i managed to move it to the place i wanted but is there a easier way to make the code more simple and accurate? Also, if you notice that I got some bad habits, let me know.

Here are the HTML and CSS (make sure to run the snippet on a full page so everything looks as it should)

```css
body {
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
background-color: rgb(53, 54, 58);
font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
color: #F3F3F3;
}

#slika {
width:120px;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
}

h1{
font-size: calc(100% + 8px);
font-weight: 400;
line-height: calc(100% + 8px);
color: rgb(232, 234, 237);}

.learn-more {
  
  color: #22e3c3;
  
}

.mid-page {
  padding-top:20px;
}

div{
margin-inline-end: 694px;
}

.a1 {
text-align: left;
list-style-position: inside;
position: relative;
left:132px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<section id="top-page">
<img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/incognito-6-902117.png" id="slika">
</section>
<section>
 <h1>You've gone incognito</h1>
  <span>Now you can browse privately and other people who use this device won't see your activity. However, downloads and bookmarks will be saved.</span>
  </br>
  <a class="learn-more" href="https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=incognito" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
</section>
<section class="mid-page">
<div>
<em>Chrome won't save the following information:</em>
</div>
<div class="bulletpoints">
<ul class="a1">
<li>Your browsing history</li>
<li>Cookies and site data</li>
<li>Information entered in forms</li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: center` in the body tag is forcing every element to be aligned in the center. Avoid mentioning position in pixels.

```css
body {

justify-content: center;
background-color: rgb(53, 54, 58);
font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
color: #F3F3F3;
}

#slika {
width:120px;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
}

h1{
font-size: calc(100% + 8px);
font-weight: 400;
line-height: calc(100% + 8px);
color: rgb(232, 234, 237);}

.learn-more {
  
  color: #22e3c3;
  
}

.mid-page {
  padding-top:20px;
  text-align:left;
}

section{
  width:40%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:justify;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    section{
      width:80%;
  }
}
#top-page{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<br>
<section id="top-page">
<img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/incognito-6-902117.png" id="slika">

 <h1>You've gone incognito</h1>
  </section>
<section>
  <span>Now you can browse privately and other people who use this device won't see your activity. However, downloads and bookmarks will be saved.</span>
  </br>
  <a class="learn-more" href="https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=incognito" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
</section>
<section class="mid-page">

<em>Chrome won't save the following information:</em>
 

 <ul class="a1">
<li>Your browsing history</li>
<li>Cookies and site data</li>
<li>Information entered in forms</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! What should i use instead of pixels?

Comment: You can just adjust the width of div using % of screen width.